# count the number of points at the end of a string

Tags: c#, .net

I need to count the number of points at the **END** of string.
The number of points in the middle of the string are not relevant and should not be countet.

How can this be done?

```
string sample = "This.is.a.sample.string.....";
```

for the example above the correct answer would be 5 because there are 5 points at the end of the string.

because of performace reasons I would prefer a fast solution. Don't know if Regular Expressions

```
\.*$
```

should be used in such a case.

Comment: Performance probably doesn't matter.  If it really does you'd need to profile / test.  One thing with regex is that you can compile a regex, making it faster to run.  Don't know what your other options are, maybe character iteration from the end of the array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from the end of the string and go back char by char until its not a dot:

```
string sample = "This.is.a.sample.string....."
int count = 0;
for (int i = sample.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (sample[i] != '.') break;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: And it seems like this would be faster, but do we know it would be faster?

Comment: faster than what?

Comment: using a compiled regex

Comment: It's probably silly - not really likely to matter.  Is he working on doing this millions of times per second? :)

Comment: I don't think there's a faster way to do this. And yes you are right, it won't really matter.

Answer (score 4):

Using Linq:

```
var test = "this.is.a.test........";
var count = test.ToCharArray().Reverse().TakeWhile(q => q == '.').Count();
```

Convert string to array, reverse, then take while character = '.'.  Count result.

Comment: Didn't see you there :-)

Comment: Not the fastest, but Linq is always nice! If not the "performace" requirement stated by the OP, this would be the solution i'd go for.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using an extension method.

```
var test = "this.is.a.test........";
Console.WriteLine(test.CountTrailingDots());

public static int CountTrailingDots(this string value)
{
    return value.Length - value.TrimEnd('.').Length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using Regex](https://regex101.com/r/gCAxUC/1):

```
int points = Regex.Match("This.is.a.sample.string....", @"^[\w\W]*?([.]*+)$").Groups[1].Value.Length;
```

**Description:**

`*+` = Matches as many characters as possible

`*?` = Matches as few characters as possible.

Comment: with `(\.*)$` I get two matches one with the dots and one empty.

The group is not necessary because it contains everything. Isn't it?

Comment: My cleaned up Regex could be: `^.*?(\.*+)$`.

Comment: I still think the author's original regex is simpler.  You could do:  `int points = Regex.Match("This.is.a.sample.string....", @"\.*$").Groups[0].Value.Length;`

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like..

```
string sample = "This.is.a.sample.string.....";
int count = 0;
if(sample.EndsWith("."))
   count = sample.Substring(sample.TrimEnd('.').Length).Length;
```